# Blazor Server Side - Session on editing a page (only one person can access at the same time)

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

One of the functionalities that will be included on my Blazor server side application, is that only one user can access a page, while others will forbid accessing it, and they can only access it when the user closes the page. I have no experience with this, even in ASP.NET Webforms and ASP.NET MVC, so this is new for me, does anyone what are the ways for me to do this?

Comment: Use a static variable somewhere in the app to track if the page is opened by someone, to do that declare a bool, in OnInitilized method set the bool to true and on dispose method set the variable to false. When the variable is already set then check it on OnnInitilized method and prevent other users to access the page, maybe redirect to another page or something..